# Get items per row in ListView to label c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm trying to create a receipt and my problem is how to get the text or item per row in `ListView` to label.

This is what i tried

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.listView1.Items)
    {
        {
            frm2.label1.Text = itemRow.SubItems[0].Text;
            frm2.label2.Text = itemRow.SubItems[1].Text;
            frm2.label3.Text = itemRow.SubItems[2].Text;
            frm2.label4.Text = itemRow.SubItems[3].Text;
            frm2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works or not ?

Comment: it works but how do i get the second row? or all rows

Comment: Yes, your code needs to be improved. If the listView1 has more than one element, each iteration in your foreach, you will overwrite the text of your labels

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to perform two loops through the list.  I've added the results to an array, but you can do whatever you want with the collected data.  If you're trying to arrange it on certain labels you can use the code below.

```
int x;
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.listView1.Items)
{   
    x = 1;
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < itemRow.SubItems.Count; i++)
           {
                 frm2.label1.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label2.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label3.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label4.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
           }
         }
         case 2:
         {
           for (int i = 0; i < itemRow.SubItems.Count; i++)
           {
                 frm2.label5.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label6.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label7.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
                 frm2.label8.Text = itemRow.SubItems[i].Text;
           }
         }
    x++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, how do i set text to label each `SubItems`? and get the `SubItems` in second row and set the text to label too?

Comment: If you're trying to arrange it on certain labels you can use the updated code

Comment: it only setting text the `SubItem[1]` is it because i add some `break;`? because i got an error without break

Comment: where did you get the error?  And, what was the error message?

Comment: It says "Control cannot fall through from one case label", but never mind i changed my label's to another `ListView` and cloned the items. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Magillanica If this was helpful, can you vote on this post and mark it as "answered question"

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<object> myListOfSubItems = new List<object>();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        myListOfSubItems.AddRange(item.SubItems);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,  but i think i can't use this code too advanced for me LOL

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked, but if second row has no item it triggers an error

`frm2.label2.Text = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text;
frm2.label3.Text = listView1.Items[1].SubItems[0].Text;`